# use of redux-thunk with redux-observable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs5, redux-thunk, redux-observable

I'm using redux-thunk to manage async stuff in my react application and I want to use redux-observable to manage complex async flow more easily (concat multiple Ajax calls for example). Is there a way to do so without modify what's already done?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
const fetchSomeData = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        doAnAjaxCall((err, response) => {
            if (err) return dispatch({type: 'ERROR', err})
            // do something
            return dispatch({type: 'SUCCESS', response})
        })
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use `fetchSomeData` inside an epic?
Since redux-thunk is promise based redux-observable should allow that, am I missing something?

Comment: I think you still need to some work on registration of epic. You can use wrap your exiting promises with observable. But I would suggest using redux-observable and remove redux-thunk both are good and have a different style of handling async actions. I like redux-observable so I could be biased.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep! You totally can use them together. Just place the redux-thunk middleware *before* the redux-observable middleware.

```
applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, epicMiddleware)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-observable-playground-8c7pd9?file=ping-pong.js

Redux applies middleware in the order they are provided as arguments, so in this case we want the thunk middleware to absorb any dispatched thunks so that the thunk functions themselves never reach redux-observable (only pure actions). But your epics can still dispatch thunks since the redux-observable middleware uses `store.dispatch` under the hood.

Comment: This example doesn't work with the latest redux-observable version any more. Please help to update with epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic) @jayphelps